# AES_ENCRYPT записывает пустую строку

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть 2 запроса

```
$sql="UPDATE `my` SET `CURRENT`=AES_ENCRYPT('BLAAA','PASS') WHERE `FULL`=11"  ; 
$sql="SELECT AES_DECRYPT(`CURRENT`,'PASS') AS `boo` FROM  `my` WHERE `FULL`=11"
```

Почему записывается пустая строчка? Аналогично она и выводится? Ошибок нету. Тип поля "text".

Comment: Используйте другой тип поля. BINARY или VARBINARY

Comment: Благодарен.Вроде получилось

Answer (score 1):

ответ скопирован из комментария.

---

Используйте другой тип поля. *BINARY* или *VARBINARY*.